# The problem of not creating a subscription after completing the order in certain conditions

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I use the [WooCommerce subscription plugin](https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-subscriptions/), By default, when the user adds a subscription product to the shopping cart and goes to the checkout page, If the payment is unsuccessful, a subscription is created pending payment, and if the payment page returns again and this time the payment is successful, the same subscription is created that is waiting for payment, the subscription number is updated and changed to active status. The following code is responsible for this:

```
    /**
     * Create subscriptions purchased on checkout.
     *
     * @param int $order_id The post_id of a shop_order post/WC_Order object
     * @param array $posted_data The data posted on checkout
     * @since 1.0.0 - Migrated from WooCommerce Subscriptions v2.0
     */
    public static function process_checkout( $order_id, $posted_data = array() ) {

        if ( ! WC_Subscriptions_Cart::cart_contains_subscription() ) {
            return;
        }

        $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

        $subscriptions = array();

        // First clear out any subscriptions created for a failed payment to give us a clean slate for creating new subscriptions
        $subscriptions = wcs_get_subscriptions_for_order( wcs_get_objects_property( $order, 'id' ), array( 'order_type' => 'parent' ) );

        if ( ! empty( $subscriptions ) ) {
            remove_action( 'before_delete_post', 'WC_Subscriptions_Manager::maybe_cancel_subscription' );
            foreach ( $subscriptions as $subscription ) {
                wp_delete_post( $subscription->get_id() );
            }
            add_action( 'before_delete_post', 'WC_Subscriptions_Manager::maybe_cancel_subscription' );
        }

        WC_Subscriptions_Cart::set_global_recurring_shipping_packages();

        // Create new subscriptions for each group of subscription products in the cart (that is not a renewal)
        foreach ( WC()->cart->recurring_carts as $recurring_cart ) {

            $subscription = self::create_subscription( $order, $recurring_cart, $posted_data ); // Exceptions are caught by WooCommerce

            if ( is_wp_error( $subscription ) ) {
                throw new Exception( $subscription->get_error_message() );
            }

            do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_subscription_created', $subscription, $order, $recurring_cart );
        }

        do_action( 'subscriptions_created_for_order', $order ); // Backward compatibility
    }
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', array( 'WC_Subscriptions_Checkout', 'process_checkout' ), 100, 2 );
```

Now, I want the subscription to be created when the order is completed, so that if, for example, a few thousand users do not make a payment, the subscription will not be automatically created for them pending payment. That's why I deleted the hook above and used the hook below :

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', array( 'WC_Subscriptions_Checkout', 'process_checkout' ), 100, 2 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', array( 'WC_Subscriptions_Checkout', 'process_checkout' ), 5 );
```

But there is a problem, When the subscription is of a variable type and the order is completed, the subscription is made in only one mode, and that is if the virtual and download ticks are put together.If only the virtual tick is ticked or only the download tick is ticked, the subscription will not be created after the order is completed, **There is no problem when the subscription is simple**.

I also tested `woocommerce_payment_complete` hook, Everything is done correctly except for one part : After successful payment, the order will be completed, but the subscription will be in pending payment status, while the subscription must be activated.

I am really confused why it happened like this

Comment: I suspect changing when the subscription is created will not be possible using custom code. The creation of the subscription is likely performed in a specific way, and the plugin doesn't expect it to be created later. You are paying for WooCommerce Subscriptions plugin, so you have access to support chat: may be worth asking why subscriptions are created before initial payment and not after, and making a feature request.